# Automatically save view as table with extra column

Tags: sql, view, automation

In my SQL database I have a view with specific data for my reporting stuff. For archiving purposes I want to automatically save that view as a table. I have created the table with a

```
SELECT * INTO t_ReportArchive FROM v_View
(Table = t_ReportArchive; View = v_View)
```

So the table is fine. The columns of the view and table will not change at any time, just the data is being updated. I am really new to SQL and my question is: Is it possible to run a script or something to automatically update the table with the new data from that view? Something like `Update t_ReportArchive from v_View`?

Comment: When you say "automatically," would you like it to be set on a timer to update daily, hourly, etc.? In that case you should look into creating stored procedures and jobs.

Comment: Create a stored proceedure and set it up as a server job

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule this query in Jobs and this can be done with the frequency you want hourly,daily weekly, monthly.

please refer the below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 0):

Well the query that you are using creates the table and inserts into the table, so it can only be used once. You could manually run in the first time to create the table bun subsequently you could use a simple insert like:

```
insert into t_ReportArchive select * FROM v_View
```

Alternatively you could create a new table for every day that the backup runs and have a date appended to that table like so:

```
declare @backupquery varchar(100) = 'select * into t_ReportArchive'+ REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10)),'-','_')+ ' from v_View' 
exec (@backupquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to run when you insert/update/delete from your table and run your SQL from there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Personally I don't like triggers, since it's hard to keep trek on what is happening. Same is correct for scheduled jobs.

I prefer to call the update from my code whenever a change happens.